Nginx multiple server same location same port different proxy pass
I'm trying setup 2 server name listening same port same location but different proxy_pass

    server {
        server_name    web.domain.com;
        root           /usr/share/nginx/html;
        index          index.html;
        try_files $uri /index.html;

        listen [::]:443 ssl ipv6only=on; # managed by Certbot
        listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
        
        location / {
                proxy_pass https://gef984f3df9b4f9.oraclecloudapps.com/ords/r/apps/;
                proxy_set_header Origin "";
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host:$server_port;
                proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
                proxy_connect_timeout 600;
                proxy_send_timeout 600;
                proxy_read_timeout 600;
                send_timeout 600;
        }

    }

    server {
        server_name    app.domain.com;
        root           /usr/share/nginx/html;
        index          index.html;
        try_files $uri /index.html;

        listen [::]:443 ssl ipv6only=on; # managed by Certbot
        listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot

        location / {
                proxy_pass https://gef984f3df9b4f9.oraclecloudapps.com/ords/r/apex/app-builder/;
                proxy_set_header Origin "";
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host:$server_port;
                proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
                proxy_connect_timeout 600;
                proxy_send_timeout 600;
                proxy_read_timeout 600;
                send_timeout 600;
        }

    }

But getting the error "nginx: [emerg] duplicate listen options for [::]:443". Is what I'm trying to achieve even possible in nginx?
